# How to test an app built with atom-shell

Tags: electron

Does anyone have an example of testing a app built with [atom-shell](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell).

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Taking a look at the spec folder of [atom-shell](https://github.com/atom/atom-shell/tree/master/spec) provides the necessary details.